# question about solving system of equations using symbolic math

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to use symbolic symbol to solve a system of linear equation. So I prepare the following code.

```
A=[1,2;3,4];

% syms x
x=sym('x_%d',[2 1]);

eqn=A*x==[1;2];

result=solve(eqn,x)
```

Interestingly, it works, but when I read the variable result, it gives a 1X1 struct with x_1 and x_2 are 1X1 sym. But what I expect get should be 2 real values, why? Could someone explain it? Remark: do not want to use A^-1*[1;2] to obtain the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you set the output to ***single variable*** `solve` returns a structure
  data type that contains all the solutions, to get each solution use
  the dot`.` assignment, like `result.x_1` or `result.x_2`

**The code is as follows**

```
A=[1,2;3,4];

% syms x
x=sym('x_%d',[2 1]);

 eqn=A*x==[1;2];
result = solve(eqn,x);
result.x_1
% 0
result.x_2
% 1/2
```

---

- If you want to have `result` as an array, use ***multiple output format***, like
  `result(1)` for the first variable, `result(2)` for the second variable

**The code is as follows**

```
A=[1,2;3,4];

% syms x
x=sym('x_%d',[2 1]);

 eqn=A*x==[1;2];

[result(1), result(2)] = solve(eqn,x);
result
% result = [0 , 1/2]
```